# Sending a scheduled message using text from database

Tags: php

Is there a way to have a user complete a web form which sent an automatic text message or email message at a scheduled time?  The user would enter the time of day they wanted to receive a text or email while completing the form. Ideally, the form would pull data from a database of text and construct the message to be sent.

What languages are needed to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

no need a specific programming language rather than programming for email script. You need to set a cron job for linux server or task schedule from windows server.
Then configure your cron job/task depending on the input of user. here is an easy tutorial for you:
http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/sending-email-alerts-through-cron/

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it may help!

Comment: Glad that i can help.